# WHERE/GROUP By Condition - One Name but multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I have the following table:

```
Name          Product         
Bob           Car              
Bob           Apples
Bob           Pears
Bob           Car
John          Apples
John          Pears
```

Whoever has bought a Product Car, I want to keep separate from everyone else. So, I create a flag:

```
Name          Product       Flag        
Bob           Car             1  
Bob           Apples          0
Bob           Pears           0  
Bob           Car             1
John          Apples          0
John          Pears           0
```

But the problem with my flag is that even if I do a where condition and say, show me the consumer WHERE flag !=1, it'll pick Bob. Which is incorrect as Bob owns a car.

I would still like to GROUP by Product.

How do I separate the above table into two groups?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `Flag` column at all.

Comment: "How do I separate the above table into two groups?" - What "groups"? Please note that `GROUP BY` in SQL does not "group" result-sets in the output, instead it's for the application of aggregate functions. Please post some example desired output because your question is unclear.

Comment: You don't need the `Flag` column at all. If your purpose is to hide the Name column to specific users, you have to create a VIEW  that is basically a `SELECT all_columns_except_name FROM your_table`, And then set specific permissions: Normal users can't access the table but can access the View

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :-

```
select name from table where flag!=1
and name not in (select name from table where flag = 1)
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two queries. The additional `Flag` column is not required.

```
-- do not have Car
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE Name not in (SELECT DISTINCT Name 
                   FROM products 
                   WHERE Product='Car');

-- have Car
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE Name in (SELECT DISTINCT Name 
               FROM products 
               WHERE Product='Car');
```

**Illustration:**

```
-- table
SELECT * FROM products;
+------+---------+
| Name | Product |
+------+---------+
| Bob  | Car     |
| Bob  | Apples  |
| Bob  | Pears   |
| Bob  | Car     |
| John | Apples  |
| John | Pears   |
+------+---------+

-- query for people that do not have Car
+------+---------+
| Name | Product |
+------+---------+
| John | Apples  |
| John | Pears   |
+------+---------+


-- query for people having 'Car'
+------+---------+
| Name | Product |
+------+---------+
| Bob  | Car     |
| Bob  | Apples  |
| Bob  | Pears   |
| Bob  | Car     |
+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

"show me the consumer WHERE flag !=1, it'll pick Bob" that is because you are asking for *rows* where flag != 1. Instead you'll need something a little more complicated, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM tableTable
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM theTable WHERE Product = 'Car')
```

alternatively, you can do a LEFT JOIN, which may or may not be faster depending on the amount of data you have and how its values are distributed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name
FROM theTable a
LEFT JOIN theTable b ON a.Name = b.Name AND b.Product = 'Car'
WHERE a.Product != 'Car' AND b.Product IS NULL
;
```

This gets all the rows with products other than cars, and then uses the LEFT JOIN in conjunction with the IS NULL condition to find which did not also have a 'Car' row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your table's data displayed, just with "People who bought cars" *partitioned* (not grouped) separately somehow - this could be done with an `ORDER BY OwnsACar` clause, for example.

Step 1: Identify the people who have bought cars:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Name
FROM
    yourTable
 WHERE
    Product = 'Car'
```

Step 2: Join on this data to generate a calculated "`OwnsACar`" column:

```
SELECT
    yourTable.Name,
    yourTable.Product,
    ISNULL( carowners.Name ) AS OwnsACar
FROM
    yourTable
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        Name
    FROM
        yourTable
    WHERE
        Product = 'Car'
    ) AS carowners ON carowners.Name = yourTable.Name
ORDER BY
    OwnsACar ASC,
    yourTable.Name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
SELECT `t`.`Name`, `t`.`Product`, SUM(`t`.`Flag`) as hasCar
FROM your_table t
GROUP BY `t`.`Name`
HAVING `t`.`hasCar` = 0;
```

Although you can go without the flag column by going :

```
SELECT `t`.`Name`, `t`.`Product`, SUM(IF(`t`.`Product` = 'Car', 1, 0)) as hasCar
FROM your_table t
GROUP BY `t`.`Name`
HAVING `t`.`hasCar` = 0;
```

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`. `SELECT * ... GROUP BY t.Name` won't even run on 99% of dbms.

Comment: Didn't get your point at all. Just added backquotes to avoid possible keywords problem, if that was what you were refering to + this is tagged as mysql.

Comment: You need to list column names when you use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Not needed on mysql in this case though, but whatever, I updated.